# Is this mushroom "Chicken of the woods"?

Tags: plant-identification, mushrooms

There's a huge mushroom growing on one of our trees and we're trying to identify what it is. One likely candidate is "chicken of the woods" which is even edible! But I'm not quite sure, so I'd like to ask the more knowledgeable people around here.

Location: Europe, Latvia.

Note that the colors in these pictures are a bit washed out - they're really much more yellow than they appear here.

Some pictures I took this year:

[image]

[image]

And last year's picture:

[image]

I have a few more photos if some important detail cannot be seen.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not chicken of the woods. It's most probably giant polypore (meripilus giganteus). Chicken of the woods is yellow-orange and has a more homogenous cap surface.